# Unable to install bluemix container CLI (cf ic) under Windows 10

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-plugin

My environment:

- Microsoft Windows 10 64bit
- Docker, version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd, installed from Docker Toolbox
- CloudFoundry CLI, cf version 6.16.1+924508c-2016-02-26
- Bluemix CLI, bx version 0.3.1-5206a18-2016-03-01T08:16:52+00:00

I typed this command `cf install-plugin https://static-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibm-containers-windows_x64.exe` under both CMD and Boot2Docker VM in order to install cf ic plugin, which is mentioned in the official guide. The result is "exit status 2".

Output:

```
Attempting to download binary file from internet address...  
10325504 bytes downloaded...  
Installing plugin C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\
ibm-containers-windows_x64.exe... 
FAILED exit status 2
```

What is "exit status 2" any way? I have found a section that mentions "exit status 1" in the troubleshooting document. However, there is no information about "exit status 1".

I installed all the programs using the default settings and the cf ic plugin did not install properly.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Boot2Docker has been deprecated for Windows
Anyway has you check that the cf cli is available on your environment?
Run
cf -v

Comment: The cf utility is fine. It was the cf ic plugin who failed to install.  I think it is a incompatibility issue with windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install the new bx plugin that include containers feature too: http://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/home.html

```
bx ic help

USAGE:
    bluemix ic COMMAND [COMMAND OPTIONS] [ARGUMENTS...]

IBM Containers commands:


attach(Docker)      Attach to a running container
build(Docker)       Build an image from a Dockerfile
create(Docker)      Create a new container
cpi                 Copy image
exec(Docker)        Run a command in a running container
groups              List all container groups
group-inspect       View the info of specified container group
group-instances     List instances of specified container group
group-create        Create a new container group
group-update        Update an existing container group
group-remove        Remove a container group
images(Docker)      List images
inspect(Docker)     Return low-level information on a container or image
info                Display information about IBM Containers
init                Initialize IBM Containers CLI
ips                 List all IP addresses
ip-request          Request an IP address
ip-release          Release an IP address
ip-bind             Bind an IP address to a container instance
ip-unbind           Unbind an IP address from a container instance
kill(Docker)        Kill a running container
namespace-get       Get current container namespace
namespace-set       Set container namespace
pause(Docker)       Pause all processes within a container
port(Docker)        List port mappings or a specific mapping for the container
ps(Docker)          List containers
restart(Docker)     Restart a running container
rm(Docker)          Remove one or more containers
rmi(Docker)         Remove one or more images
run(Docker)         Run a command in a new container
route-map           Map a route to container group
route-unmap         Unmap a route from container group
start(Docker)       Start a stopped container
stats(Docker)       Display a live stream of container(s) resource usage statistics
stop(Docker)        Stop a running container
top(Docker)         Display the running processes of a container
unpause(Docker)     Unpause a paused container
volumes             List all volumes
volume-inspect      View the info of specified volume
volume-create       Create a new volume
volume-remove       Remove a volume
volume-fs           List filesystems
volume-fs-create    Create a new filesystem
volume-fs-remove    Remove a filesystem
volume-fs-inspect   Inspect a filesystem
volume-fs-flavors   List filesystem flavors
version(Docker)     Show the Docker version information
wait(Docker)        Block until a container stops, then print its exit code
help
```